# A way to store java files in SQL?

Tags: java, sql, file, html

This may be a dumb question, but I have a project for a class where I have to store/retrieve files from a SQL database that connects to a web page. Now, I could just make a webpage to store pictures or music files but I am currently working on creating some basic games in java. I know that there are ways to be able to access these files from a web page, but like I said, the project has to include a SQL database.

So my question is, is there any way to store and retrieve these kinds of files from the SQL database? Being able to download the files would be fine as long as the user would be able to open them, though I would prefer the user be able to open them in the browser.

If anybody has any suggestions I would appreciate it.

Comment: You mean the user should be able to edit these java source files on the net?

Comment: If your RDBMS has a CLOB datatype, that might work.

Comment: Are you talking about .class compiled files are .java source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When storing into a SQL database, you don't really store the files.  You store the file contents.  In it's most generic form, you could make a table with a big binary field (a blob or clob depending on which database you use) or a big text field (a varchar) and put the contents of the file into that.  Other columns could store file names and such.

To really leverage the SQL database, you would want to know enough about the content of the files to take advantage of indexing and such by breaking it up into more detailed parts.  For example, if you are putting a save file in there, you could make a detailed table with columns for username, and all sorts of game-specific state that needs to be saved.